# orientdb supsplk HIGH resource usage

Tags: orientdb

I am having an issue where the command: supsplk is taking up all my CPU resource. It says the user is orientdb, the weird thing is when I kill it it just come back up. Any help would be great. There is also very little information on the web for supsplk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supsplk has been seen [here](https://www.reverse.it/sample/dd93f36dd1b18ca4a2ad46a17fd9ac5991f720c0627fabe07a87e4e3b8cd7ea9?environmentId=300)

It appears to be a crypto mining task, and your system is likely to have been compromised.

There's some analysis of recent crypto mining task behavior [here](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2018/02/cve-2017-10271-used-to-deliver-cryptominers.html)

Perhaps your system was vulnerable to **CVE-2017-10271**?

Comment: Thank you. We killed the processes.